# How to protect a website from xss (Cross site scripting)

Tags: php, mysql, security, xss

Ok so i've  learned a bit of PHP and tried making a simple application but i am not sure is my webpage secure from xss and other such attacks .

My PHP CODE

```
<?php 
$title=$keywords=$description="";
$valid_er="";


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

if(empty($_POST['title'])){

$valid_er="has-error";
}

else{
$title="&lt;title&gt;".test($_POST["title"])."&lt;title&gt;";
}


$keywords='&lt;meta name="keywords" content="'.test($_POST["keywords"]).'" /&gt;';
$description='&lt;meta name="description" content="'.test($_POST['description']).'" /&gt;';

}

function test($ci){

$ci=htmlentities($ci);
$ci=stripcslashes($ci);
return $ci;
}


?>
```

And MY HTML FORM

```
<form method='post' class='form-group' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<label> Your Title  </label> <input placeholder="Your websites title" type="text" name="title" class='form-control' class='form-group-item'/></br>
<label> Keywords </label> <input placeholder="Your keywords separated by comma " type="text" name="keywords" class='form-control' class='form-group-item'/></br>
<label>Description </label> <textarea  placeholder="A nice description about your website;" name="description" class='form-control'></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" class='btn btn-info'>

    </form>
```

I just wanted to know am i vulnerable to cross site scripting , because i don't think only using

> htmlspecialchars()

will protect me .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Comment: if you can tell me is my code secured , it will be really helpful

Comment: You don't need to use stripcslashes to escape HTML. htmlspecialchars is enough. Also, when you write HTML in your PHP code, you shouldn't use escaped characters such as `&lt;`, because they will be printed in the browser instead of being interpreted.
Basically : when YOU write HTML, write it normally ; when you display something coming from an user input, use htmlspecialchars. Does this help?

Comment: actually i had earlier made the same code for adding the value of name therefore as  name doesn't contain slashes i did all that but i used the same code  . And i am using &lt; because i want to display "<" . Your reply really helped thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just wanted to know am i vulnerable to cross site scripting

No, you are not, and just using `htmlspecialchars` will protect you against XSS in most cases (if you use double quotes around attributes and follow the rules in my last paragraph).

You don't need to use `stripcslashes`, and you don't need to encode your own `<`, etc.

Do note however that `htmlspecialchars` does not encode a single quote (`'`) by default. I mention this because for your `form` tag, you mainly use single quotes, and just double quotes for the action,which is a really good idea, as otherwise your code would be vulnerable to XSS. To avoid this problem, you can use `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`, with which single quotes would also be encoded. You still can't just omit using any quotes (if you do that, preventing XSS becomes a lot more complicated, as you would need to escape all characters with which you can break out of that context, which include space, `+`, etc), but with this, you can use double or single quotes and be safe.

For more information, check out this site about [XSS prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) (it tells you where this kind of encoding is not enough; you should never put user input inside `<script>`, `<style>`, HTML comments, attribute names, or tag names).

Comment: thank you for your help , i will surely implement all your tips .

Comment: Why is `htmlentities` recommended over `htmlspecialchars`? And `htmlspecialchars` *does* replace the double quote `"` by default, it’s the single quote `'` that isn’t replaced by default.

Comment: @Gumbo thanks, you are of course right about the quotes. And I take back what I said about `htmlentities`, it doesn't offer anything that `htmlspecialchars` doesn't offer (regarding XSS).